# Remove string values that differ only in case from an array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, anagram

So, here's the preface:

I'm quite a beginner in Ruby. I'm working on a anagram finding script (find all anagrams in a text file). The essence is: I create a dictionary where key is word code and value is an array with words that refer to this code. It is like that: `{"abdeis"=>["abides", "biased"] ,"achr"=>["char"], ... }`. In the end I just print out the values with length of >1. So good so far.

Here's the deal: I want to modify the output, so that such cases are omitted: `["Wood", "wood", "WooD"]` - all are different in case only. But such cases should stay: `["Doom", "DooM", "mood"]`.

My current piece of code:

```
def print_anagram(anagram_dict)
  anagram_list = anagram_dict.values
  anagram_list.each { |i|
    if i.length > 1
      print i.join("\t")
      print "\n"
    else
      next
    end
   }
end
```

anagram_dict is a dictionary mentioned above.

What checks should I make to throw these cases away? The things I think of seem way to bulky to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the difference between ["Wood", "WooD"] and ["Doom", "DooM"].

Comment: @steenslag: the doom array also included "mood", the wood array only "wood"

Comment: "The things I think of seem way too bulky to me."  What things have you thought of?  This almost looks like homework and if it is should be tagged as such, and it isn't forbidden here.  In answer to your question. I would probably make everything the same and call unique on it

Comment: @vgoff The homework tag is obsolete (try searching for it).

Comment: Thanks @steenslag.  I saw about 4800 of them, so was unaware until now.  Still could give full disclosure in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def print_anagram(anagram_dict)
  anagram_list = anagram_dict.values
  anagram_list.each do |i|
    next if i.map(&:downcase).uniq.length == 1

    if i.length > 1
      print i.join("\t")
      print "\n"
    else
      next
    end
  end
end
```

What this does:

- make all Strings lowercase
- get only unique elements from the array
- if you only have one unique element, all elements are the same

`map(&:downcase)` is a shorter way of doing: `map { |element| element.downcase }`

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! I will now try to find some other solutions on this, maybe fiddle with Array#reject a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
def print_anagram(anagram_dict)
  anagram_list = anagram_dict.values.uniq{|word| word.downcase}
  # rest of your code
```

Comment: I see what you mean here, that is something of the kind I was looking for. It should work, but for some reason it raises an error for me: `undefined method `downcase' for ["A's"]:Array (NoMethodError)`. I will try to debug stuff to see what is going wrong.